# Openshift how to access shared folders

Tags: node.js, openshift

I am using nodejs to write a file in a shared drive and it is working fine in my local machine, however after deploying the above code in Openshift the file is not creating and it is because OpenShift is not able to access the folder. Below is my code:

```
writeFile() {
        const sharedFolderPath = "\\server\folder";
        fs.writeFile(sharedFolderPath, templatePath, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                console.info("file created successfully");
            }
        })
    }
```

How to configure share folder with credentials in Openshift so that my code could write the file?

Answer (score 1):

If this is server side, and you are using OpenShift S2I builder for NodeJS, you can only write to directories under `/opt/app-root`.

If you need data to survive a restart of the container, then you need to use a persistent volume. You can then mount the volume anywhere so long as doesn't overlap a directory which had other stuff in it you need to still access. Using persistent volumes which are `ReadWriteOnce` means you will need though to switch deployment strategy from default of `Rolling` to `Recreate`.

Answer (score 1):

By default, OpenShift runs images with arbitrary user ids, e.g. 1000010000, so if it works locally, but not on OpenShift, it could be that the directory is not writable for that user.

The following is from the [OpenShift Guidelines](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/creating_images/guidelines.html#openshift-specific-guidelines) for creating images (emphasis is mine):

> #### Support Arbitrary User IDs
>
> In order to support running containers with volumes mounted in a secure fashion, images should be capable of being run as any arbitrary user ID. When OpenShift mounts volumes for a container, it configures the volume so it can only be written to be a particular user ID, and then runs the image using that same user ID. This ensures the volume is only accessible to the appropriate container, but requires the image be able to run as an arbitrary user ID.
>
> To accomplish this, **directories that must be written to by processes in the image should be world-writable**. In addition, the processes running in the container must not listen on privileged ports (ports below 1024).

So you might need to add a `RUN chmod 777 /server/folder` to your Dockerfile to make that directory world-writable.